$G$-invariant field equations
It is easily verifiable that if we are given a field theory with the Klein Gordon equation, it is Poincaré-invariant. So is the Dirac equation. More generally, for arbitrary spin, the Poincaré-invariant wave equations  are the Joos-Weinberg equations. Is the converse true as well? Is there a mathematical theorem (proved somewhere in the literature), which states that invariance with respect to a group $G$ determines uniquely a class of field equations? Or is this too vague to be stated as a mathematical theorem? What further restrictions/conditions could lead to an answer of the question? Perhaps a classification of $G$-invariant Lagrangians can be given?
Similarly, is there a Galilean/Carrollian analogue of the Joos-Weinberg equations?

It's not true that $G$-covariance implies a unique set of field equations. Even if the matter content is fixed, any $G$-invariant Lagrangian built out of those fields will produce $G$-covariant field equations. There are many such Lagrangians because there are many potentials you can build out of a fixed set of fields.
If you make some assumptions about the theory that end up picking out a unique Lagrangian, then you could have the converse to your theorem. For example, you could assume that your matter was in a fixed irreducible representation (i.e., has a fixed spin) and make some kind of minimalism assumption on the potential/ number of derivatives, then you do get uniqueness. That being said, that's kind of cheating because you in essence just reduced the space of possible theories until you got the converse to hold, which isn't exactly what you're looking for.

I also haven't discussed the fact that not all theories have Lagrangians, which I'm sure complicates the story I presented. Then again, those theories tend to be "special" and hard to "deform" so they do have unique equations of motion in some sense.

what if we fix minimal coupling, under fundamental rep of fields? Does the converse hold in this case? Also, what about free theories?

Any questions you're asking about the EOM are better asked in terms of the Lagrangian. You're trying to use assumptions about the dynamics as well as the kinematics to deduce the unique EOM. But those assumptions first specify a Lagrangian, and then the EOM follow from there. So as long as you fix a set of assumptions which picks out a unique Lagrangian (just as minimal coupling, free theories etc) then there will indeed be unique EOM.
